# How can I translate a linux batch file into a windows bat file?

Tags: windows, linux, batch-file

I need to translate a linux batch file into a windows bat file.

```
for FILE in *.tif
do
  NEWFILE=../lowres/${FILE}
  gdal_translate -outsize 25% 25% $FILE $NEWFILE
done
```

I don´t know how to set a variable in a windows bat file.

Thanks for any help,

cheers,

Rob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what `${FILE}` does, the following runs;

```
gdal_translate -outsize 25% 25% "XXX.tif" "../lowres/XXX.tif"
```

for each .tif in the current directory;

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%f in (*.tif) do (
    set newfile=../lowres/%%f
    gdal_translate -outsize 25%% 25%% "%%f" "%newfile%"
)
```

Comment: ${FILE} keeps the output file name the same as the input

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off

for %%A in (*.tif) do @call somecommand -outsize 25%% 25%% "%%~nxA" "../lowres/%%~nxA"

REM or

setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
for %%A in (*.tif) do (
    set newfile=../lowres/%%~nxA
    call somecommand -outsize 25%% 25%% "%%~nxA" "!newfile!"
)
```

Run `for /?` for more details about the ~ variable expansion and `set /?` for details about delayed expansion...

Comment: ~nxA ? don´t know what this does...it produces errors though unfortunately

Comment: @RobertBuckley %%A is the output from the for command (path depends on what you passed in the "in (xyz)" part), %%~A strips quotes and enables the expansion of other things, nx = name+extension. %%A will probably work in your case. Do "debug" you can replace call with echo to see what you would be executing...